# How do I load this form theme from my App Bundle? (symfony)

Tags: symfony

I have an app with the following directory structure in Symfony 2.6

```
src/
    App/
        MainBundle/
            Forms/
                template.html.twig
```

And I'm trying to use this as a form theme along with the bootstrap3 theme. According to the documentation I can apply multiple themes. So I've updated `config.yml` to look like this:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    form:
        resources: 
            - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
            - 'AppMainBundle:Forms:template.html.twig'
```

However, when I add the second resource I only get a blank page. It must be something to do with the way I'm referencing the template -- I can reference another one of the built-in ones and it works correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates need to be saved under the

```
src/{bundle name}/Resources/views/{subdir}/{twig filename}
```

e.g.

```
AppMainBundle:Forms:template.html.twig:

src/App/MainBundle/Resources/views/Forms/template.html.twig
```

Comment: This doesn't really feel truly like a view since its only used with the form builder -- is there no way to reference these outside the views folder?

Comment: There is always a way but then you don't follow the conventions. And i think it is in the right place because it is part of one or more of your pages that needs to be rendered. Besides you are still able to put it in a separate directory (Forms)